# C#: Sorting by ID XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am working on bit safe data in XML through C#, It seem fine. But I when I received tags by ID it gives information as:

> 1 10 11 12 ... 19 and then 2 20 21 22 23 and 3 30 31 etc...

Not in sequence. How I get with perfect sequence.

Note. In xml ID of element is not set as sequence the reason why I am making it strict while reverting tags by ID. at the time I use following code for sorting

```
var recListVar = recList.OfType<XmlElement>().OrderBy(items => items.GetAttribute("id"));
```

I bet that this kind a sorting is good for alphabet not for Numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you get all the number, you can simply use `int.Parse` for sorting:

```
var recListVar = recList.OfType<XmlElement>()
                  .OrderBy(items => int.Parse(items.GetAttribute("id")));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know you will only get strings that can be parsed into an int, use [Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx)

```
var recListVar = recList.OfType<XmlElement>().OrderBy(items => int.Parse(items.GetAttribute("id")));
```